# Get token from activation url sended from server

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer

I'm newbie to coding login systems and now I'm coding an account activation logic after registration.

I'm sending an email to the registered user with an url like this:

```
127.0.0.1:3000/activate/(token here)
```

And I'm handling it on server side when user access to that url on this way:

```
app.get('/activate', ( req, res) => {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + '/public/activation.html')
})
```

But of course there's not a handler for every unique token so I need a way to access to enter on that app.get... /activate but kinda ignoring the second part where the token is so the file is served but keeping this token in a variable to operate with it later on it's inside logic.

How can achieve it? Am I totally wrong on my approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic link

```js
app.get("/activation/:token",(req,res,next)=>{
  
  const token = req.params.token;
  //don't use token directly in sql database 
});
```

Comment: That totally made the trick, thanks! Why shouldn't I use that token on SQL? I mean, I have it previously stored for that user, I only need to make a query using that token to select that user and change its status to "activated" instead of "on_registration"

Comment: it risk sql injection but  can strict the token format. just make sure don't allow "-" for basic cases.